# Flutter: how to lazily load list in full-page scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

### **Context**

I have a Flutter web app where I am trying to lazily load a list of 50 items on a page using `ListView.builder()`. The page has full-page scroll (i.e. the root widget is wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView()`).

### **Problem**

In order to maintain a full-page scroll, I cannot set a finite height for the parent element of the `ListView.builder()`. Without a finite height though, one has to use `shrinkWrap: true` in the `ListView.builder()` to make it work. That however causes a problem -- `shrinkWrap` forces all the children (the list items) to evaluate immediately, meaning it no longer loads items lazily and consequently there is a lag in the list being rendered.

I have included a sample app below that illustrates the problem. Install the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get/install) package first, then run the app in Flutter web. Once the app is running, use the buttons to switch between Page 1 and Page 2. You'll notice:

- **Page 1**: has full-page scroll but the page stalls/lags when rendering because the items aren't loaded lazily (`shrinkWrap` causes all list items to build at once).
- **Page 2**: it is no longer a full-page scroll (it only scrolls to the finite height we've set) but the page renders immediately because the items are indeed loaded lazily.

### **My question**

How can I achieve a page that both (a) has full-page scroll with all items and (b) loads the list lazily? I have tried various things (normal `ListView()`, `ListView.builder()`, `List.generate()`, `Column()`, `CustomScrollView()` with `SliverList()`), but no luck.

NOTE: I also tried using `DataTable` but as explained [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70510), the row heights in `DataTable` do not adjust to fit the content when multiple items are in the DataCells (which is my case).

### **Sample code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      defaultTransition: Transition.noTransition,
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => const Page1()),
        GetPage(name: '/page1', page: () => const Page1()),
        GetPage(name: '/page2', page: () => const Page2()),
      ],
    );
  }
}

final items = List<String>.generate(1000, (i) => 'Item $i');

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const TopNavBar('Page 1'),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true, // needed because parent element does not have a finite height.
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                debugPrint('Page 1: building item $index');
                return ListTile(
                  title: Center(child: Text(items[index])),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const TopNavBar('Page 2'),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: ListView.builder(
                // shrinkWrap: true, // not needed because we set a finite height in parent element.
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  debugPrint('Page 2: building item $index');
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Center(child: Text(items[index])),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopNavBar(this.pageTitle, {super.key});

  final String pageTitle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Text(pageTitle, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 28)),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            OutlinedButton(onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/page1'), child: const Text('Page 1')),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            OutlinedButton(onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/page2'), child: const Text('Page 2')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it can be of help to anyone else, the solution is indeed to use a `CustomScrollView` with slivers that fit your need. More about the topic [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY-_yrZdjGc). Also, the [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) package offers some additional slivers for more customisation to fit your needs. Here is a great [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVxd0K_74Pc) on that package.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
   SliverAppBar(),
   SliverList(),
   SliverToBoxAdapter(),
  ]
)
```